# Numerical integration when solving PDE: Simpsons rule and high frequency noise

Tags: pde, numerical-analysis, integration

I am solving a PDE, and one of the intermediate steps is to numerically integrate a function over a compact interval. The function is represented on a linearly spaced grid. I am using Simpsons rule (so I use the value of the integrand at $x_i$,$x_{i-1}$ and $x_{i-2}$ as well as the value of the integral at $x_{i-2}$ to obtain the integral at $x_i$) , but sometimes I get a zigzag noise after integrating. I know why (in the Simpsons rule the even numered points $x_{2i}$ and the odd $x_{2i+1}$ are sort of obtained separately, and depend a lot on the error of the first point $x_0$ and $x_1$. But the error there is greater since one must use a lower order routine since simpsons rule requires three points).

How can I fix this? What are the state of the art integration routines on linearly spaced grids?

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackExchange! It would help if you could expand your questions with the formulas that describe what exactly it is you're trying to do. As it stands, there is simply too little detail in the question to allow anyone to really figure out what the problem may be.

Comment: I also find it difficult to understand what exactly you are doing. Would you mind posting the procedure you are following in full detail?